# How to convert raster map to shapefile (raster map boundaries to vector center line shapefile)

Tags: conv-neural-network, gdal, image-preprocessing, ogr, osgeo

I have a raster map in tiff format and I am trying to convert it into smooth shape file. but I guess due to pencil drawn lines its output is in the weird shape file which you can show in the screen shots.

Input tiff file (it is in greyscale):

[This is input_image.tif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhS9W.png)

[This is its zoom version where we can there are some pixels which are not visible correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYJ3b.png)

Code: i am using gdal library:

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import gdal, osr

# Specify the input TIFF file path
input_tiff = 'input_image3.tif'

# Specify the output shapefile path
output_shapefile = 'outputs/output3.shp'

# Open the TIFF file
ds = gdal.Open(input_tiff)

# Get the raster layer
layer = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# Create a new shapefile layer for polylines
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
shapefile = driver.CreateDataSource(output_shapefile)
layer_name = 'polylines'

# Create a new layer with the correct spatial reference
spatial_ref = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=ds.GetProjection())
new_layer = shapefile.CreateLayer(layer_name, geom_type=ogr.wkbLineString, srs=spatial_ref)

# Convert raster to vector

gdal.Polygonize(layer, None, new_layer, -1, [], callback=None)

# Perform simplification

# Clean up
ds = None
shapefile = None

print("Conversion completed successfully.")
```

output shape files:

[This is the output of above code in shape file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAiQv.jpg)

[This is zoom version of same above shapefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6NUz.jpg)

[This full zoom version where we can see the small polygons which is not required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmhrr.jpg)

In the output I want just single line not tiny small polygonized lines.

here is required Output shapefile:

[Ignore the inside numbers, I just want boundaries of raster tiff file into shape file like this single lines instead weird tiny small boxes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxUWO.jpg)

If anyone knows how to deal with this problem please let me. I have tries many methods all the Chat GPT suggest but those not working. I guess first I have to digitized my pencil map sketch. I have tested by giving a tiff file which was drawn by computer then its output was correct. I don't know to how to preprocess this image to extract lines.

[required output shapefile (ignore the numbers inside the boxes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxNPM.jpg)